# Суммирование в столбцах QTable - компонента Quasar

Tags: vue.js, таблицы, quasar-framework

Вроде функционала такого нет в стандартном описании. Но все же, интересно, как это реализовать. Интересует как суммирование всех строк в текущем представлении, так и при использовании фильтра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template lang="pug">
q-table(:data="items")
  template(#bottom)
    pre {{sum}}
</template>

<script>
...
data () {
  return {
    items: [ 
      {col1: 1, col2: 2, ..., colN: 0},
      {col1: 3, col2: 5, ..., colN: 2},
      ...,
      {col1: 2, col2: 3, ..., colN: 4},
    ]
  }
},
computed: {
  sum () {
    const sum = {
      col1: 0,
      col2: 0,
      ...
      colN: 0
    }
    return this.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc.col1 += item.col1
      acc.col2 += item.col2
      ...
      acc.colN += item.colN
    }, sum)
  }
}
...
</script>
```